# Why does Acabado theme block all js files in plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I created a wordpress plugin which has a shortcode. In my public files which related to shortcode I have added js files as follows.

```
 public function enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( "jquery");   
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugins_url( '/js/wp-like-feedback-tool-public.js',__FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, "owt_like_feedback", array(
    "ajaxurl" => admin_url("admin-ajax.php")
));
```

}

Problem is all the js files doesn't load. Does Acabado theme block js files default? Is there any way to solve this or is there a specific way to append js files with Acabado theme?